# What is the concise way to write following code segment in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, if-statement

I am learning Kotlin and I have written following code snippets in Kotlin.
Rather than using if-else condition is there any concise way to write following code?

```
fun test(a: int, b: int): Coding {
   return Coding().apply{
    if(a>b){
     comment = "first value greater than second value"
     value = a
    }else{
     comment = "second value greater than or equal to first value"
     value = b
    }  
   }
}
```

Comment: This is not valid Kotlin: 1. The function name is missing. 2. "int" is not a type, correct is "Int". 3. There is no value returned, but the function's definition requires a string to be returned.

Answer (score 5):

```
comment = if (a > b) "first value grater than second value" else "second value grater than or equal to first value"
value = max(a, b)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace with a `when` expression as below;

```
   when {
            a > b -> {
               comment = "first value grater than second value"
               value = a
            }
            else -> {
               comment = "second value grater than or equal to first value"
               value = b
            }
      }
```

But as per docs also, if the condition is a simple binary condition, use `if` statements. If you have to handle more than three conditions, prefer `when`. More info https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#if-versus-when

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Laksitha and @Twistleton answers a combination of both suggestions:

```
val (value, comment) = when {
  a > b -> a to "first value greater than second value"
  else  -> b to "second value greater than or equal to first value"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a Kotlin one-liner with an if expression:

```
 val a = 5 
 val b = 9 

 val (value, comment) = if (a > b) Pair(a, "first value greater than second value") else Pair(b, "second value greater than or equal to first value")
```

Pair represents a generic pair of two values.